# Coldfusion exception while calling the webservice

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, jboss, axis

I have written a portlet which consumes a simple webservice. When i deploy it into jboss, it is throwing below exception. I tried by adding coldfusion.jar into build path. but no luck. Can any one help me on this?

```
2012-11-21 20:31:03,919 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: coldfusion.xml.rpc.RequestHeaderHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: coldfusion.xml.rpc.RequestHeaderHandler
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:212)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getJavaClass(WSDDDeployableItem.java:353)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:295)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getHandler(WSDDDeployment.java:394)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:276)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.test.MyWebserviceSoapBindingStub.addition(MyWebserviceSoapBindingStub.java:121)
    at com.test.SampleWebservice.doView(SampleWebservice.java:30)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:348)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:253)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.services.container.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.services.container.FilterChainImpl.processFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:91)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.services.container.FilterManagerImpl.processFilter(FilterManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.driver.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:340)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.driver.PortletServlet.doPost(PortletServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:557)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:481)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.container.DefaultPortletInvokerService.invoke(DefaultPortletInvokerService.java:233)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.container.DefaultPortletInvokerService.render(DefaultPortletInvokerService.java:117)
    at org.apache.pluto.container.impl.PortletContainerImpl.doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:157)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.tags.PortletTag.doStartTag(PortletTag.java:165)
    at org.apache.jsp.ns360.portletfrag_jsp._jspx_meth_pluto_005fportlet_005f0(portletfrag_jsp.java:393)
    at org.apache.jsp.ns360.portletfrag_jsp._jspService(portletfrag_jsp.java:166)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:557)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:481)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jsp.ns360.portalhome_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(portalhome_jsp.java:395)
    at org.apache.jsp.ns360.portalhome_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f1(portalhome_jsp.java:296)
    at org.apache.jsp.ns360.portalhome_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(portalhome_jsp.java:132)
    at org.apache.jsp.ns360.portalhome_jsp._jspService(portalhome_jsp.java:85)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.PortalDriverServlet.doGet(PortalDriverServlet.java:214)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.PortalDriverServlet.doPost(PortalDriverServlet.java:233)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.pluto.driver.ns.PortalFilter.doFilter(PortalFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.newscale.bfw.signon.filters.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Thank You.